# Error occured while importing the global variables in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have taken two python modules i,e. **GenericFunctions.py** and **Login_CSA.py**

In **GenericFunctions.py** i declared global variables and i imported those variables in **Login_CSA.py**

but while writing any print statements with those variables it is showing error message like

***"Undefined variable from import"***

### code in GenericFunctions.py

```
global g_TargetEnvironment
global g_TargetRegion
global g_TargetSystem
global g_TCDataSheet
global g_Remarks
```

### code in Login_CSA.py

```
import GenericFunctions

    def Login_CSA(p_TargetEnvironment, p_TargetSystem, p_TargetRegion, p_TCDataSheet, p_TCOutputFile, p_TargetoptLevel, p_TCaseID, p_TCDescription):

        #Script to clear all the global variables declared
        nullifyglobal=GenericFunctions.fn_NullifyGlobal()
         #Script to close any existing firefox is there or not
        closeexistingfirefox=GenericFunctions.fn_CloseExistingFFBrowser()

        GenericFunctions.g_TargetEnvironment = p_TargetEnvironment
        print "g_TargetEnvironment : ", GenericFunctions.g_TargetEnvironment
        GenericFunctions.g_TargetSystem = p_TargetSystem
        print "g_TargetSystem : " , GenericFunctions.g_TargetSystem
        GenericFunctions.g_TargetRegion = p_TargetRegion
        GenericFunctions.g_TCDataSheet = p_TCDataSheet
        GenericFunctions.g_TCDataSheet = GenericFunctions.g_TCDataSheet+".xlsx"
```

iam getting error at  "print "g_TargetEnvironment : ", GenericFunctions.g_TargetEnvironment" , """GenericFunctions.g_TCDataSheet = GenericFunctions.g_TCDataSheet+".xlsx" """ this statement

can u guys pls help me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
global g_TargetEnvironment
global g_TargetRegion
global g_TargetSystem
global g_TCDataSheet
global g_Remarks
```

to:

```
g_TargetEnvironment = None
g_TargetRegion = None
g_TargetSystem = None
g_TCDataSheet = None
g_Remarks = None
```

Comment: by declaring like above my issue is fixed but i have a doubt that how can be those variables are global by not giving the global keyword

Comment: They are outside a function, so they are global anyway.